# How to call multiple methods by URI segments in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes

I have an issue with CodeIgniter; I have a controller named `site`, and in this controller there are two methods: `production` and `story`.

`production` calls a specific production via a model which creates `production/slug`.

What I want to achieve is to create the following URL:

```
site/production/slug/story
```

How do I achieve that? As the slug changes, in the story function I want to call a story from the database using `$this->uri->segment(3)`.

Comment: Have tried with codeigniter route?

Comment: I do not really get how I should route it, although I have read the documentation for it

Comment: @user2599060 Is this problem resolved? any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `method` name as second parameter to the first method.
For example, if the URI is `site/production/slug/story`, pass `story` to the `production` method and do necessary checks as below:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct()
    }

    public function story($text) {
        echo $text;
    }

    public function production($slug = '', $callback = NULL)
    {
        // Do something with $slug

        if (isset($callback) && method_exists(__CLASS__, $callback)) {
            $this->{$callback}($slug);
        }
    }
}
```

**[PHPFiddle Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/mnv-3a1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can post multi parameters:

```
URI: site/production/slug/story/5

public function production($one, $two, $there)
{
    echo $one."<br />";
    echo $two."<br />";
    echo $there."<br />";
}

# OUTPUT
slug
story
5
```